# Swift: Location permission popup keeps closing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, location, cllocation

While attempting to get a users longitude and latitude in Swift, I have run into an issue. I have a button that runs a function to get the user's coordinates, the first time it's pressed, it should ask for permission to give the app your location. But, the issue I am having is that this popup will automatically close right after I press the get location button.

Here is what happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw2XT.jpg

Here is my code:

```
class location: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

internal func getLocation() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedAlways {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    } else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    } else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .Denied {
        print("User denied location permissions.")
    }
}


// MARK : CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol
@objc
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = (locationManager.location?.coordinate)!
    print(location.latitude)
    print(location.longitude)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code where you allocate your `location` class instance. It sounds like it is being released, when it should remain for the duration of your app. You should consider making it a singleton

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code which works for me. Some things to take note of:

1. Only create a `CLLocationManager` when you actually need to use it. If the user hasn't enabled CoreLocation then they will get an alert when the location manager is created, which could be when your app launches (which may or may not be what you want).
2. `requestAlwaysAuthorization` requires a `[NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription][1]` entry in Info.plist.
3. Observe `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` and stop the location manager if the services becomes unavailable.

Code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class LocationViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

    internal func getLocation() {

        if locationManager == nil {

            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager?.delegate = self
            locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        }

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedAlways {
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
            locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        } else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .Denied {
            print("User denied location permissions.")
        }
    }


    // MARK : CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        switch status {

        case .AuthorizedAlways, .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()

        default:
            locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    @objc func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        guard let location = locationManager?.location?.coordinate else {
            return
        }

        print(location.latitude)
        print(location.longitude)
    }
}

extension LocationViewController {

    @IBAction internal func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        getLocation()
    }
}
```

Comment: Even after trying your code, I am still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

when location permission popup appear you shouldn't access location anymore.You just need to wait for user permission than keep using location related features.